# Custom Buttons in C# WinForms

Tags: c#, winforms, button

I have done a bit of research but cannot seem to find what I am looking for.

What I want to do is make a "custom" button in a windows form. This would basically just be a matter of changing the default "grey" background to a custom image. A custom image would also be used for when hovering over and clicking the button.

This is not just a matter of changing the background image as the image I want to use has rounded edges with a transparent background and I want custom image for hovering / clicked. I want everything else about the button to behave in the same manner as a normal button.

Is this possible?

Comment: Sounds more like you want to use WPF. However, do you have the option to move to WPF or are you stuck in Windows Forms?

Comment: I am pretty much restricted to Windows Forms for this.

Comment: The fastest route from here to there is likely to be to license the control you need, not write it from scratch.

Comment: The Button class is a bit unusual in Winforms, it has very few options to alter its appearance with code.  There a four distinct button renderer classes but they are all private.  You'll need to derive your own class from ButtonBase.  That base class has enough plumbing to make your class *behave* like a button, but not enough to make it *look* like a button.  Well, that's what you want to change.

Comment: @BradSemrad This has nothing to do with WPF.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The solution I found was to set the **FlatStyle** of the button to **Flat** and set all the borders to 0. I then had a problem with the focus of the button (it displayed a little border). To solve this I followed this tutorial:

http://dotnetstep.blogspot.com/2009/06/remove-focus-rectangle-from-button.html

With this in place all I had to do was add events to the button so that the image was changed when a certain action was carried out on it:

```
    private void button1_MouseLeave(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.button1.Image = Properties.Resources._default;
    }

    private void button1_MouseEnter(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.button1.Image = Properties.Resources._hover;
    }        

    private void button1_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        this.button1.Image = Properties.Resources._clicked;
    }

    private void button1_MouseUp(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        this.button1.Image = Properties.Resources._default;
    }
```

Hope this will help someone else!

Answer (score 3):

It is called owner-drawn button

refer to:
[Mick Dohertys' .net Tips and Tricks - Tips / Button](http://dotnetrix.co.uk/button.htm)
[GlowButton - A Glowing Button Control](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/61201/GlowButton-A-Glowing-Button-Control)
[A shiny orb button in GDI+](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/22596/A-shiny-orb-button-in-GDI)

Comment: thanks for the reply. Hmmm this looks like it will be a long task! i'll take a look into it.