# Is there a RichTextButton in C#?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, richtext

You know the [RichTextBox](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.windows.forms.richtextbox(v=vs.110).aspx). Is there an easy way to get a "RichTextButton" in WinForms? Think about the [button](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_button.asp) tag in HTML, which allows something like a rich text button.

I want to add some text formatting to buttons in C#/.NET.

Comment: In WPF, sure.  In WinForms you'd be looking for 3rd party controls or would have to create your own.

Comment: See [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/9320854/464709) for pointers.

Comment: No, no such thing. You need either owner-drawing the button or a bitmap it displays.

Comment: You can write your own custom control that inherits from the base button class, then modify the sections you need to.

Comment: No, there isn't. And there shouldn't be. Most people who try and do this just end up uglifying their application, defeating accessibility, and making it more difficult to use. The reason web applications have this is because it's a giant hack; they don't *have* a standard button type provided by the window manager. Windows applications do, you get it using the `Button` control. Why do you need "formatting" in a button?